# Laravel select with multiple tables

Tags: laravel

I am making adjustments to a mp3 player partly programmed in laravel. Since I am new to this language, I would like ask for some help. Any comments on this are highly appreciated!

The mp3 player offers the ability to work with multiple genres. In each genre a number of songs are present. Each song can be upvoted or downvoted (or not be voted). A visitor can only upvote or downvote once each song.

For this piece of code two tables matter: songs and actions. Please find two screenshots included.

Songs table [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qPNv.png)

Actions table [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NurqL.png)

I would like that a rondom songs is shown which is enabled (table songs) and the unique user has not downvoted (Disliked), in other words the user has not voted on the song (not recorded in table) or upvoted the song (Like).

For this to work I am struggling with the code between //---. All the other code is working properly.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Genre;
use App\Song;
use App\Action;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
public function index(Request $request){
    if(isset($_COOKIE['authuser'])){
        $authuser = $_COOKIE['authuser'];
    }else{
        $authuser = 'u'.uniqid();
        setcookie('authuser', $authuser, time()  + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
    }
    $selectedGenre = Genre::first();

    //---       
    $song = $selectedGenre->songs()->where('isEnabled',1);
    $action = $song->actions()->where('name', 'Like')->where('authuser', $authuser);
    ->inRandomOrder()->first()
    //---

    $song->playcount++;
    $song->save();

    $genres = Genre::orderBy('priority', 'ASC')->get();

    return view('index', compact(['song', 'genres', 'selectedGenre', 'authuser']));
}
```

Again, any help is highly appreciated! :)

Comment: When you do `dd($song,$action);`, what do you get?

Comment: Hi Eitan, thank you for your reply! You mean an output like this?

Song {#217 ▼
  #fillable: array:4 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:9 [▶]
  #original: array:9 [▶]
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}

Comment: HasMany {#203 ▼
  #foreignKey: "actions.song_id"
  #localKey: "id"
  #query: Builder {#210 ▶}
  #parent: Song {#217 ▶}
  #related: Action {#211 ▶}
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$randomSong = $selectedGenre->songs()->where('isEnabled',1)
->whereDoesntHave('actions', function ($q) use ($authUser) {
    $q->where('authUser', $authUser);
})->inRandomOrder()->first();
```

Oh and word of advice, don't use $_ variables. Always better to use Laravel's wrappers such as `$request->cookie('name')`

Comment: Hi Paras, thank you so much for your post! Please note that  'actions' is another table. Within this 'actions table' ' song_id' , 'name' (Like or Dislike)  and ' authuser'  are relevant. Maybe it is possible to link both tables by using 'id' in the 'songs' table and 'song_id' in 'actions' table? Your help is very much appreciated!